# Devise update user without password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to update users attributes without password in devise. The case is like, if password and password confirmation fields are not blank then I need devise error and if they are blank then other user attributes need to be updated. How could I do this with devise?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Is this what you're look for? From the Devise wiki

[Allow users to edit their account without providing a password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

It shows how to do it for rails 3 and rails 4

=======================

[John's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11676957/600953) is a simpler alternative

Comment: José Valim has since [deleted a lot of info](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password/_compare/0f5513cd1228d5ac1a655c601e3002d1de5a1cfb...d5dd456432b53d37827a4f4f4b4ad34e12efed12) on that wiki to advise users to write their own controllers and not override methods in inherited `Devise::RegistrationsController`s. One can look at the [wiki history](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password/_history) for previous versions, but consider his advice.

Answer (score 97):

I think this is a much better solution:

```
if params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
    params[:user].delete(:password)
    params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
end
```

This prevents you from having to change the Devise controller by simply removing the password field from the form response if it is blank.

Just be sure to use this *before* `@user.attributes = params[:user]` or whatever you use in your `update` action to set the new parameters from the form.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: where do you put this?

Comment: @MoMolog Follow the first part of Devise's tutorial: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Just create a blank custom registrations controller. Once you do that, copy the update function on the standard Devise registrations controller from here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

Place John's code at the top of your controller.

Replace "update_resource(resource, account_update_params)" with "@user.update_attributes(account_update_params)"

Comment: can you put it in the model? @onichase

Comment: How does this solution work? by deleting the password, does it bypass the validation that compares it with `current_password`? I'm not seeing how deleting `password` and `password_confirmation` gets rid of the `current_password` requirement. Where are the `current_password` validations? Isn't the `current_password` still going to be on the form, and thus validated on the client side for presence, and remain in the params hash when you update attributes?

Comment: This solution does not consider `current_password`. It is designed for the case where all user attributes (name, email, etc.) are shown *in addition to* fields for changing the password. Without logic like this, Devise will not allow any attributes to be updated if the user submits the form having changed other fields while leaving the password fields empty.

Comment: Duncan Robertson's answer is the simplest as of 2014.

Answer (score 23):

I think with Devise 3.2+ you can just override update_resource in your subclassed controller. Here's an example for the question originally asked:

```
class MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end
end
```

Comment: This answer that rules them all, by far the easiest as of 2015.

Comment: Just make sure and update your routes: `devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}`

Comment: Ok for me but I also had to add `attr_accessor :current_password` to my User model. Kind of hacks I don't like. Should I?

Comment: You can simply add `params.delete :current_password` before `resource.update_without_password(params)`

Comment: It's also officially documented way https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem as follows: if form submitting with password, then need fill current_password field or form updated without password and current_password

in model:

```
class User
  devise: bla-bla-bla

  attr_accessor :current_password
end
```

In controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController <  Devise::RegistrationsController
  layout 'application'


   def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)


    # custom logic
    if params[:user][:password].present?
      result = resource.update_with_password(params[resource_name])
    else
      result = resource.update_without_password(params[resource_name])
    end

    # standart devise behaviour
    if result
      if is_navigational_format?
        if resource.respond_to?(:pending_reconfirmation?) && resource.pending_reconfirmation?
          flash_key = :update_needs_confirmation
        end
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key || :updated
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This answer is most complete and the solution is the best

Answer (score 5):

If you still want to support password change but make it optional, check the availability of `current_password` as such:

```
class MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    if params[:current_password].blank?
     resource.update_without_password(params.except(:current_password))
    else
      resource.update_with_password(params)
    end
  end
end
```

That way if the current_password is present you can proceed and update the password, else ignore it and update without password.

Answer (score 5):

params[:user][:password] is not working in rails 6

You have to change **params[:user][:password]** to **params[:password]**

**Remove [:user] in all params**

my source code is below

before run this command

> rails generate devise:controllers users -c=registrations

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    puts "params ===> #{params}"
    if params[:password].blank? && params[:password_confirmation].blank?
      params.delete(:password)
      params.delete(:password_confirmation)
      params.delete(:current_password)
      resource.update_without_password(params)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Anyone visiting in 2020, this is the simplest solution I found:

in `registrations_controller.rb`:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    # Require current password if user is trying to change password.
    return super if params["password"]&.present?

    # Allows user to update registration information without password.
    resource.update_without_password(params.except("current_password"))
  end
end
```

In routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  registrations: 'users/registrations'
}
```

Full credit to: **Masatoshi Nishiguchi**

https://www.mnishiguchi.com/2017/11/24/rails-devise-edit-account-without-password/

Comment: Should be changed as being The answer to this question. BTW, this is also the official documentation in the current documentation.

Comment: Updated, working credit source: https://mnishiguchi-2019.netlify.app/2017/11/24/rails-devise-edit-account-without-password/

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem with my interface. There are two ways it can go.

#### Disable the fields if they are empty

This bit of jQuery disables the fields before the form submits in the event that they are empty. It requires a certain markup pattern, check the [demo on Codepen](http://codepen.io/ryanburnette/pen/ogegye).

```
$(".password-fields").each(function() {
  var $fields, $form;
  $form = $(this).parents("form");
  $fields = $(this).find("input");
  $form.on("submit", function() {
    $fields.each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === "") {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

#### Give the user a checkbox to select if they want to update

Another option is to remove the password fields from the form if the user hasn't indicated that they want to update their password. Here's the example [on CodePen](http://codepen.io/ryanburnette/pen/ogegEw).

```
$(".password-fields").each(function () {
  var $fields, $button, html;
  $fields = $(this);
  $button = $fields.prev(".update-password").find("input");
  html = $fields.html();

  $button
    .on("change", function () {
      if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
        $fields.html(html);
      }
      else {
        $fields.html("");
      }
    })
    .prop("checked", "checked")
    .click();
});
```

In either case, it requires no update to the app itself. You are just submitting the fields you want to change.

Answer (score 3):

I instead override #password_required? method inside user model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :validatable #, ...

  def password_required?
    if respond_to?(:reset_password_token)
      return true if reset_password_token.present?
    end
    return true if new_record?
    password.present? || password_confirmation.present?
  end
end
```

So if user is new he will be required to specify password.
However exist user will be required to specify password only if he fills in either password or password_confirmation attributes.

For more details see:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L33

My implementation is almost identical as original:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L53

except that I check for presence (which returns false for blank strings)

Here's discussion about my pull request on this matter: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/3920

Answer (score 3):

For future Googlers, I just spent 3 hours on this, here's what worked for me.

In my User model I remove :validatable and added validates method for the password and password_confirmation only if they are present:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registranable, recoverable, :rememberable
    
  validates :password, length: { in: 6..128 }, if: lambda {self.password.present?}
  validates_confirmation_of :password, if: lambda {self.password.present?}
end
```

Then in my users_controller's update method I delete the password and password_confirmation params if they are blank

```
class UsersController > ApplicationController
  def update
    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete(:password)
      params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Simple, plain, easy and no jerking around with Devise's convoluted way of doing things.

You're all welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Devise to check current password **only when user tries to change password** (*that means you **can** change other attributes without providing current password*):

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

    def update_resource(resource, params)
      if params[:password].blank? && params[:password_confirmation].blank?
      resource.update_without_password(params)
    else
     super
    end
  end
end
```

Also in your model:

```
attr_accessor :current_password
```

And don't forget about

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
```

in **routes.rb**.

Answer (score 1):

It's more business logic so I wouldn't put too much code in the controller. I suggest overriding `Devise::Models::Validatable#password_required?` in your model:

```
def password_required?
  new_record? || password.present? || password_confirmation.present?
end
```

Comment: This is by far the best method of doing this. Also the most customizable, as one can specify exactly for which attributes the password is required.

Answer (score 1):

As workaround put in your User model

```
def password_required?
  encrypted_password.blank? || encrypted_password_changed?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this slight variation on the code above easier to follow:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  method = if user_params[:password].blank?
             :update_without_password
           else
             :update_with_password

  if @user.send(method, user_params)
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'User settings were saved.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and this the solution I came up with and believe me it works.
What i did is create a second `user_params` method and named it `user_params_no_pass` anyway take a look: what is happening here is that the admin will provide a password when the password need to be updated else leave the password blank. when the password is blank the `user_params_no_pass` is used else `user_params`. I hope that helps

```
    def update

    if @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
          respond_to do |format|

            if @user.update(user_params)
              format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User profile was successfully updated.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
            else
             format.html { render :new }
             format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
    else
      respond_to do |format|

            if @user.update(user_params_no_pass)
              format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User profile was successfully updated without password.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
            else
              format.html { render :edit }
              format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
    end
  end

  def destroy
     @user.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
  end
  private

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:user_name, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :dob, :gender, :race, :hispanic, :leader, :mentor, :student, :email, :organization_id, :password, :opus,
  :release_date, :days_to_release, :current_level, :is_active)
    end


    def user_params_no_pass
      params.require(:user).permit(:user_name, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :dob, :gender, :race, :hispanic, :leader, :mentor, :student, :email, :organization_id, :opus,
  :release_date, :days_to_release, :current_level, :is_active)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

After much exploration of the above possibilities I finally found a solution which allows you to update some attributes without a password and some with:

I made a view for user/edit.html.erb with the following form in it.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes"%>
<% end %>
```

I set routes in routes.rb

```
resources :users, only: [:show, :index, :edit, :update]
```

I made edit and update methods in users_controller.rb

```
def edit
  @user = current_user
end

def update
  @user = current_user
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end


def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar, :whatsup)
end
```

I used this edit view for changes which did not require a password.  It skips the devise registration controller entirely because I link to it with

```
edit_user_path(current_user)
```

I also set the params so that email and password cannot be changed here.  To update password and email, I link to the stock generated devise view:

```
edit_user_registration_path(current_user)
```

I admit that this is a huge work around but none of the simpler solutions solved all of the above problems.

Answer (score 0):

Better and short way: add check params into the user_params block.
For example:

```
def user_params
    up = params.require(:user).permit(
      %i[first_name last_name role_id email encrypted_password
         reset_password_token reset_password_sent_at remember_created_at
         password password_confirmation]
    )

    if up[:password].blank? && up[:password_confirmation].blank?
      up.delete(:password)
      up.delete(:password_confirmation)
    end
    up
end
```

Answer (score 0):

to update attributes for user, you will need to use :current_password, to check 'do your user use correct current_password or someone wants to break your user'

so in form:

```
= f.input :current_password,
          hint: "we need your current password to confirm your changes",
          required: true,
          input_html: { autocomplete: "current-password" }
```

in controller:

```
    if your_user.valid_password?(params[:user][:current_password])
        your_user.update_attributes(user_params.except(:current_password, :password, :password_confirmation))
    end
```

the first line checks 'do your user sends the correct password or not', and then we can to update the attributes without garbage

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to update the password without the current_password then you need to use the user `reset_password` method

```
@user.reset_password(params[:user][:password], params[:user][:password_confirmation])
```

Here is a complete working solution to the problem that works in all scenarios:

```
  if params.dig(:user, :password).blank?
    updated = @user.update_without_password(params[:user].to_unsafe_hash)
  else
    if params.dig(:user, :current_password).nil?
      @user.reset_password(params[:user][:password], params[:user][:password_confirmation])

      updated = @user.update_without_password(params[:user].to_unsafe_hash)
    else
      updated = @user.update_with_password(params[:user].to_unsafe_hash)
    end

    bypass_sign_in(@user)
  end
```