# ActiveAdmin: Separate form for some of the fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, content-management-system, activeadmin

We are using ActiveAdmin currently as our main CMS.

For the User model, I want to add a 'Change Password' button which takes you to a form with two fields: 'password' and 'password confirmation'. The form should submit and update only those two fields for the given user. I want to do this all the while keeping the standard form for editing all other attributes.

Is this even possible with ActiveAdmin's DSL, or do I have to get a bit hacky? Their documentation hasn't been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out [ActiveAdmin: how to leave user password unchanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292247/activeadmin-how-to-leave-user-password-unchanged) - that should cover the standard form. The change password action can then be implemented with a member action.