# ActiveAdmin - Edit Devise user without changing password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, passwords, activeadmin

I try to do that. Unfortunately I have problems with overriding update and I don't know how to do that correctly. The way I do that in another place is:

```
if params[:user][:password].blank?
  params[:user].delete("password")
  params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
end
# ...
user.save!
```

So I tried to override `update`

```
def update
  if params[:user][:password].blank?
    params[:user].delete("password")
    params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
  end
  super
end
```

But it doesn't works. I still get `can't be blank` near to the password input. How to achieve expected behaviour?

Answer (score 17):

I take the answer of @anonymousxxx and add the following:

If you're using rails admin, you can override the controller "User" as follows:

```
#app/admin/user.rb
controller do
  def update
    if params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
      params[:user].delete("password")
      params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
    end
    super
  end
end
```

You should also note that, if you have the User model validations, specify when such validations are applied, for example:

```
validates :name, :email, presence: true
validates :password, :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create
validates :password, confirmation: true
```

This allows me to validate password presence only when I create a new user and update without changing his password.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Instead of adding `validates` to the model to make the field not required, you can also use the following in the `form do |f|` block in `app/admin/users.rb`: `f.input :password, required: f.object.new_record?`

Answer (score 12):

Add this code to your user model. This will do the trick for you.

```
# User.rb

private    
def password_required?
  new_record? ? super : false
end
```

Comment: Should be flagged as the answer

Comment: Be aware that this has side-effects in regards to the password confirmation field. When a user wants to change his password for example then the password_confirmation field is not required anymore..

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me :

```
def update
     @user = User.find(current_user.id)
     params[:user].delete(:current_password)
     if @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
       redirect_to ....
     else
       render ....
     end
end
```

or

```
def update
    if params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
        params[:user].delete(:password)
        params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
    end
    super
end
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11676957/1297435)

Comment: My solution works too, after removal of `validates :password, :presence => true`. I assume, that Device's validations are enough.