# Current password can't be blank when updating devise account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, user-accounts

I am using `devise` and I want to allow the user to update his account (email & password). So when I click on `edit_user_registration_path`, I get a page where the user can change his email and password. But when submitting this `update` form I constantly get this message :

```
1 error prohibited this user from being saved: ×
Current password can't be blank
```

in my `ApplicationController`, I have

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :surname, :email, :user_name, :terms_of_service, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
end
```

Someone can explain that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Devise update user without password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113248/devise-update-user-without-password)

Answer (score 5):

By default, Devise has three password fields on `edit_user_registration`: password, password_confirmation and current_password: [default registrations/edit.html.erb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb)

current_password is required for any change; the other two can be left blank if the password is not supposed to be changed.

Comment: After adding the `current_password` field, I get this message : `undefined local variable or method unconfirmed_email`. Where does this error comes from ?

Comment: @user1611830 where exactly is the error raised? What file, what line?

Comment: in this file `method_missing(gem) activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb` in the `method_missing` method `match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super`

Comment: @user1611830 please update your question with the new problem and add the full stacktrace, as well as your edit view.

Comment: ok, I caught it, I had some `:confirmable` in my devise user model ! So I deleted and it went ok !

Answer (score 5):

Place this code in your User model:

```
def update_with_password(params, *options)
    current_password = params.delete(:current_password)

    if params[:password].blank?
      params.delete(:password)
      params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
    end

    result = if params[:password].blank? || valid_password?(current_password)
      update_attributes(params, *options)
    else
      self.assign_attributes(params, *options)
      self.valid?
      self.errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
      false
    end

    clean_up_passwords
    result
end
```

Comment: Is right to pretend to have `params` inside a model? I thought they were just in controllers' context.

Comment: @PioneerSkies It's Ok and this answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default devise requires password to update the user.

Here's a page with officail instructions to change this behaviour: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you got the solution, but u can do a simple thing:

Create an user_controller, and then, create a user_params with password and password_confirmation and another one (I used this name: user_params_without_password) without password and password_confirmation.

And in your update, you will check if password is present, is yes, you will use user_params, if not, user_params_without_password.

Here is the code:

```
def update

    if params[:user][:password].present?
      params = user_params
    else
      params = user_params_without_password
    end

def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit( params...

def user_params_without_password
  params.require(:user).permit( params without password
```

I hope this hint can help you :)