# Where can I find devise controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to apply this post ( [Devise update user without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113248/devise-update-user-without-password/11676957#11676957) ) for users don't need to insert password to update informations.
But, I'm very confused where is this controller. Devise don't create any controller in my `app/controller` folder. I search in all the folders but I cant find.

Where I that controller?
I see posts talking about create a new controller, but I just want to modify little things.

Answer (score 2):

You don't edit (or shouldn't) the Devise controllers.  Instead you create your own controller and inherent from the Devise controller.

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def update
    # add custom update logic here
  end
end
```

Notice how `RegistrationsController` inherets from `Devise::RegistrationsController`.  Now you can overide the registration methods (or modify them and call `super`).  Even the [page you are referencing](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) about overriding the devise default behavior relies on class inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

JTG offers good advice, you shouldn't edit the gem directly.  As a more direct answer to the question:

To print the folder of your gem:

```
$ bundle show devise
```

To open the gem in a text editor ( while being sure not to change anything )

```
$ bundle open devise
```