# i want to update the user profile using the devise gem without update the password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**[my controller]**
 this question seems to be similar to one of the question ask on the same topic but it different because the answer given in that is not work for me

i want to update the user profile but when i try to update using the devise gem or override the update action it wouldn't be update it give 
error password_confirmation can'nt be blank

```
 def update 
   binding.pry
   @user = User.where(:id => current_user.id)
  if @user.update(update_params)
    render :json => {:user => @user.to_json }
   else
    render :json => {:error => @user.errors.full_messages.first}
  end
end  

 private
   def user_params
    params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number,:password_confirmation, :password, :city) 
   end

def update_params
  params.permit(:first_name, :last_name,:phone_number, :city) 
end
```

end

Comment: possible duplicate of [Devise update user without password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113248/devise-update-user-without-password)

Answer (score 0):

You can go through link below

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
     resource.update_without_password(params)
  end
end
```

For more information, please have a look into this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)