# Devise edit user without password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I was reading the [documentation on devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) on how to allow users to edit their account without password. Follow their first suggestion, I get an

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password confirmation can't be blank
```

my controller:

```
class UserPreferencesController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def update_profile
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update!(account_params)
      sign_in @user, :bypass
      render json: [], status: 201
    else
      render json: [], status: 422
    end
  end

  def account_params
    params[:user].permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :sex, :phone_number, :location, :birthday)
  end

end
```

I tried the second

```
def update_resource(resource, params)
  resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

Same error. So how do I update the user in devise without password and via json

Comment: Please update your question with the form code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113248/devise-update-user-without-password][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the [`password_required?`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L53) in the model you are updating:

```
def password_required?
  false
end
```

That would be enough to edit/update the resource without providing the password.