# how to save profile without entering password in devise gem of ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have used the gem devise for login logout sign up edit profile, but i want to delete the change password option from edit profile as after saving it is asking enter current password to save the changes.

Comment: `@user.update_attributes(password: params[:user][:password])` write this in in application controller where you config update params

Comment: You can check this answer, I think it is the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113248/devise-update-user-without-password