# devise: update user on another controller without password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

how can I update my user without the required password, password confirmation and current password?

I'm trying to update the user outside devise controller, my form is working with this helper:

```
module ContentHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

and my form for editing:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, multipart: true }) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>


    <%= f.file_field :personal_file, placeholder: "Upload file" %>

    <%= f.submit %>

     <%   end %>
```

With this its appearing that I can't have my password blank and redirecting to user edit page:

```
Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)
Password can't be blank
Current password can't be blank
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write up your own controller that updates *User* as you wish. Something like

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def update
    current_user.update(user_params)
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:personal_file)
  end
end
```

would do the trick. You don't need to think of the `current_user` as some magic devise thing but instead use it as any other model you have.

If you anyway wish to use Devise controller to do this, you should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5113248/1744702) answer.