# Devise Admin Edit User failing for password "can't be blank". What are the possible levels of code down to DB that can block this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've got `Devise` and `omniauth` gems. I more or less followed railscasts for multiple authentications so have Users and Authentications models.

I've managed to have a user update their own profile without a password when they have authentications.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    if current_user.authentications.empty?
      resource.update_with_password(account_update_params)
    else
      params.except("current_password")
      resource.update_without_password(account_update_params)
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: 'registrations'}, path_prefix: 'my'
resources :users
```

**users/edit.html.haml**

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @user, html: {multipart: true} do |f|  %>
  ... 
<%= f.submit "Update" %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  Rails.logger.info(params.inspect)
  if @user.update_without_password(account_update_params)
    flash[:success] = "User updated by admin."
    redirect_to @user
  else
    Rails.logger.info(@user.errors.inspect) 
    flash[:alert] = "User update by admin failed to save"
    render 'edit'
  end

  private
  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :username, :dob,:city, :state, :zip, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end

end
```

**user.rb**

```
def update_without_password(params, *options)
  params.delete(:password)
  params.delete(:password_confirmation)
  result = update_attributes(params, *options)
  clean_up_passwords
  result
end
```

**Log file**:

```
Started GET "/users/2/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-18 19:45:01 -0400
Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (12.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_sidenav.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_nav_top.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_notice.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 193ms (Views: 190.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started PATCH "/users/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-18 19:45:04 -0400
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SwkF8C+P6iExhc1ju91C9xFgaR5GSKwy8KFJUaBtHCTKzEXmPIKhaAFHlfMO+6u4/UOM0y2IAAIkpfTsuBOX6g==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Bobby", "last_name"=>"", "username"=>"", "dob"=>"", "gender"=>"", "address1"=>"", "address2"=>"", "state"=>"", "zip"=>"", "email"=>"test@test.com"}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"SwkF8C+P6iExhc1ju91C9xFgaR5GSKwy8KFJUaBtHCTKzEXmPIKhaAFHlfMO+6u4/UOM0y2IAAIkpfTsuBOX6g==", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Bobby", "last_name"=>"", "username"=>"", "dob"=>"", "gender"=>"", "address1"=>"", "address2"=>"", "state"=>"", "zip"=>"", "email"=>"test@test.com"}, "commit"=>"Update", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"2"} permitted: false>
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Authentication Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "authentications" WHERE "authentications"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Authentication Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "authentications" WHERE "authentications"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f9cf49d1758 @base=#<User id: 2, email: "test@test.com", created_at: "2017-06-18 16:05:51", updated_at: "2017-06-18 16:05:51", username: "", first_name: "Bobby", last_name: "", dob: nil, gender: "", address1: "", address2: "", city: nil, state: "", zip: "", admin: false, phone: nil>, @messages={:password=>["can't be blank"]}, @details={:password=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
  Rendering users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (5.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_sidenav.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_nav_top.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_notice.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 199ms (Views: 188.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

The message `@messages={:password=>["can't be blank"]` is pointing to the answer, but everything I've tried isn't removing this requirement. I thought that Devise's `update_without_password` method would work out of the box.

I've even tried this at the top in **user.rb**.

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 120}, on: :create
validates :password, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 120}, on: :update, allow_blank: true
```

Thanks for the help SO!

Comment: Are you getting this error when you're trying to update a user profile from activeAdmin ?

Comment: I don't have activeAdmin setup. I have an Admin boolean on the user model. This error is only occurring when my Admin attempts to update a user (via the users_controller.rb), not when a user attempts to update themselves (via registrations_controller.rb).

Answer (score 0):

Check out your `UsersController`. You are using [except](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except) on your `params`and then using `account_update_params` in the conditional. `except` doesn't exactly delete the `key` and `value` from the `Hash`.

This is a helpful SO answer that should fix your situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113248/devise-update-user-without-password) .

If that doesn't help I would follow Devise's existing guide on how to achieve this:

Make sure you follow the `Devise` guide for allowing users to edit their account [without providing a password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password). I'm not sure what you are trying to do in your `User` model, are you trying to overwrite the `Devise` method?

If you are trying to overwrite the `Devise` method you should look at the method itself:

```
def update_without_password(params, *options)
  params.delete(:email)
  super(params)
end
```

> If you are using this method, you should probably override this method to protect other attributes you would not like to be updated without a password.

Change your `RegistrationsController` to the match the docs:

```
def update_resource(resource, params)
  resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

Then follow the remaining two steps and confirm your edited your view and routes.

If you need to make any changes authentication wise be sure to change the `update_resource` method.

Comment: thanks for the help so far. I did check out that SO answer pointing to Devise wiki "How To: Allow users to edit their account without providing a password". My update_resource from registrations_controller.rb works for a user updating themself. My problem is an admin updating a user via users_controller.rb. Your comment on params.except - I tried something on this and will update OP.

Comment: Why not use `current_user.authentications.present?` in your `UsersController`?

Comment: current_user is an admin. The @user being edited is a different instance. So the current_user 's having or not having authentications should not matter to the instance being edited.

Comment: Are you doing some sort of impersonation? Then instead of `current_user` use the `authentications` on the `@user` you are trying to change?

Comment: Using byebug. Once users_controller.rb #update is hit and the flow goes through if @user.update_without_password(account_update_params), to the user.rb model def update_without_password(params, *options) method, I used byebug to just try and save a change to the user model (using self.first_name = "Test", then self.save!, and it's still giving me the :password=>["can't be blank" message.